# dividing algorithm which calls a function by cpu cores, and running the function on a GPU kernel

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, opencl

I'm just messing around trying to learn a little bit about parallel computing.  If have a something that looks like this,

```
long A[12];
long B[5,000,000];
long C[12];
long long total=0;
long long tmp; 

GPUKernel(){

    for (n=0; n < 5,000,000; ++n) {
        B[n]=0;
    }

        for (n=0; n < 5,000,000; ++n) {
             for (n2=0; n2 < 12; ++n2) {
                 B[n]+=C[A[n2]];   
             }
             tmp+=B[n];      
        }  

     if (tmp > total) {
         total=tmp;
         tmp=0;
     } 
 }



int main(){

    srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) );   

    for (n=0; n < 12; ++n) {
        C[n]=rand() % 1000000;
    }

    for (n=0 ; n < 8916100448256 ; ++n) {    
        ++A[0];
        for (p=0; n<11; ++p) {
            if (A[p]==12) {
                A[p]=0;         
                ++A[p+1];
            } 
        }
    GPUKernel();
    }

 return 0;   
}
```

My idea is that I'll get the number of threads the CPU can use.  For example, if there are 4, and I'll make separate copies of all the data for how every many cpu threads I make.  So each gpu kernel will have it's own data as well.  Does this make sense?  Would this be a good way of going about this task?

```
//cpu core 1
for (n=0; n < 8916100448256/4 ; ++n) {
    ...
GPUKernel1();
}

//cpu core 2
for (n=(8916100448256/4; n < (8916100448256/4)*2 ; ++n) {
   ...  
GPUKernel2();
}

//cpu core 3
for (n=(8916100448256/4)*2; n < (8916100448256/4)*3 ; ++n) {
   ...       
GPUKernel3();
}

//cpu core 4
for (n=(8916100448256/4)*3; n < 8916100448256) ; ++n) {
   ...      
GPUKernel4();
}
```

Comment: Where does `p` come into things? I never see it declared or defined.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake, I edited it to look more like how it is supposed to.  There are probably a lot of logical errors and mistakes still, please don't worry about the validity of the code so much as the way I want to structure it for parallel computing.

Comment: And where does the GPU and OpenCl come into the question? The way you have structured the code is complete orthogonal to the GPU programming model. For the GPU, you would start with the idea that there would be _5 million_ threads and work from there.

Comment: @talonmies I guess I'm  not smart enough yet to think of how to do that.  Right now I'm just trying to figure out how to accomplish the origional serial code in parallel.  The problem I think I am facing is that the data cannot be shared between the threads I put on the CPU, and I can't make thousands of copies of that data, but I can make 4, or 8 etc copies of it.  And the part the gpu is doing can be broken up into millions of threads.  So long as each kernel isn't sharing data with the other.

Comment: @user1120229: ask yourself why you need any copies of the original data at all? The data is only read, not written to, so parallel access is no problem no matter how many threads you have. The trick in this operation is how to efficiently combine the partial sums held by each thread. The operation is called a parallel reduction and there is a huge amount of theory and literature around on it, including GPU implementations. Google is your friend. As it stands this is a really poor question and I am voting to close it....

Comment: "The trick in this operation is how to efficiently combine the partial sums held by each thread."  This is difficult for me to know how to do.  All I needed was some verification on whether this idea was way off or not.  Now I know not to invest too much time with this.  I'll go back to reading.

Comment: Also, what about B?  B is written to trillions of times.

Comment: @talonmies, I still can't see it.  I think you may have not understood the code properly.  A is written to with a specific combination of data chosen by the part in the main function.

Comment: @user1120229: Look at the data dependencies in the calculations - `C` is constant and `A` is completely independent of `GPUKernel`. Inside `GPUKernel` the calculation of `B[n]` is embarassingly parallel. The only section of the code which requires interaction between threads is the summation/maximum calculation which can be also be done in parallel.

Comment: @talonmies.  I guess your right.  I may have miss wrote the code, or I may just be confused all together.  I know that the GPU kernel is easy to make parallel, and have it going in parrallel already on cpu cores.  The part in the main function I was unable to get to work right, and I think at least in my other code there might be a race condition.  But besides that, the part I proposed to put on the GPU kernel takes thousands of times longer to execute than the part in the main function anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but this seems like an algorithms questions. OpenCL is nowhere in the picture. BTW, when you write kernel code in OpenCL/CUDA the data allocated to each thread will be determined by the thread ID of that thread, you can divide them in terms of blocks etc. Please refer to the Programming guide(NVIDIA/AMD).

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but if I use the NVIDIA implementation of openCL, it will still work on AMD card and vice versa right?  Which implementation do you think is the best?

Comment: No, it's not stupid. Actually, the **performance** depends on the architecture. AMD uses VLIW, so you need to vectorize to get high performance whereas NVIDIA uses superscalar. Memory optimizations are also a bit different

Comment: For your next question, I think that AMD (Cypress-20 SIMDs, 2.72 GFlop/s peak single-precision) cards give higher performance compared to NVIDIA cards(Fermi - max. 16 SIMDs, 1.03 TFLop/s peak single precision) provided they are optimized for that architecture. Each of the vendors have introduced `#pragmas` which provides the user the ability to debug the kernel etc.